# JS script is unable to detect images in a page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

I want to use this script to detect all images on a page (not svg) . I start on the detection of IMG, DIV tags and look inside the classes that correspond to a regular expression and the CSS background-image property (which works, I tested it). But nothing is detected. Any idea ?

i try this code :

```
// my regex that looks for the right classes and the right html tags (div img)
const regex = /(stk-[0-9a-f]{7}-container|uag-image-\d+|wp-image-\d+)/;

// Browse all img and div tags
document.querySelectorAll('img, div').forEach(element => {
  // does the element contain a class corresponding to the regular expression
  const match = element.className.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    // Extract the identifier of the image from the class
    const attachmentId = match[0].match(/\d+/)[0];

    // Extract the EXIF data of the image from the background-image property
    const bgImage = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('background-image');
    if (bgImage && bgImage.includes(attachmentId)) {
      exifr.parse(bgImage.slice(4, -1))
        .then(output => {
          // Display datas on console
          console.log(output);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

I was waiting for the exifs of the images in the console
but nothing at all

Comment: use the code `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event)` to make sure all elements are included